# iOS device must show the banner to user when receive apple Extension-Push-Notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app receive push notification through Extension.
there are some content that app receive from server that not necessary show the banner to the user.
I would like to know that if app not show the banner to user when receive push notification through extension, does apple ban the push to my app?

Comment: A notification extension can change the content of the notification but it cannot chose not to show a notification. It is not the apple will "ban" anything, there just isn't an option in the extension api to not show a notification.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I was believing there is a way to not show notification.